# Ethereum: could not open database: resource temporarily unavailable

Tags: meteor, ethereum

I am getting started with Ethereum and building a Dapp (what the hell does this mean by the way?). On the basic installation of the application (https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Dapp-using-Meteor#connect-your-%C3%90app), I get this error upon attempting to connect.

```
geth --rpc --rpccorsdomain "http://localhost:3000"
I0804 23:48:24.987448 ethdb/database.go:82] Alloted 128MB cache and 1024 file handles to /Users/( . )Y( . )/Library/Ethereum/chaindata
Fatal: Could not open database: resource temporarily unavailable
```

I literally just got started, I set up ethereum through homebrew and made an account with geth. Can't get past right here.

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `geth` client is [already running in the background](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/2120/87). You can attach to it by typing:

```
$ geth attach
```

in your command line. This will allow you to run commands on the `geth` client console.

Comment: Thank you for your help! When I do this, it just puts me into the console. I do not know how to move on from here and execute the command I wanted to earlier.

Comment: Well you already have that line if you reach this point. Go on with the tutorial.